# How to sort numbers alphabetically using Tablesorter?

Tags: jquery, html-table, tablesorter

I'm using Tablesorter to sort a multi-column table.

One column of my table has numbers that I would like to sort **alphabetically**, eg. `10, 111, 2, 4444, 55, 9`.

How do I disable the number detection in Tablesorter and let it sort all as text ?

Just setting:

```
headers: {
  0: { sorter: "text" },
}
```

didn't work.

Comment: If that doesn't work probably need to write a custom sorter for that column. Docs show how to use custom sorters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this parser works in every case you need, but it works with the subset of data provided ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/bbxxomhx/1846/))

```
$(function() {
    $.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: "nums",
    is: function() { return false; },
    format: function(s) {
        var first = s.charAt(0);
      return first + "-" + s.substring(1);
    },
    type: "text"

  })
  $('table').tablesorter({
    headers: {
      0: {
        sorter: "nums"
      }
    }
  });
});
```